# How to join correctly join words that trails or heads of dashes? - python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list of strings that contains tokens that ends or starts with `-` I need to join them up such that the words with dashes join up into the correct tokens, e.g.

**[in]:**

```
x = "ko- zo- fond- w- a (* nga- bantawana )."
y = "ngi -leth- el a -unfundi"
z = "ba- ya -gula buye incdai- fv -buye"
```

**[out]:**

```
kozofondwa (* ngabantawana ).
ngilethel aunfundi
bayagula buye incdaifvbuye
```

I've been doing it as such, it's real ugly and inelegant especially when i need to call the function twice. Is there other way to achieve the same output? maybe with regex or something?

```
x = "ko- zo- fond- w- a (* nga- bantawana )."
y = "ngi -leth- el a -unfundi"
z = "ba- ya -gula buye incdai- fv -buye"
def join_morph(text):
  tempstr = ""
  outstr = []
  for i in text.split():
    if i.startswith('-'):
      outstr[len(outstr)-1]+=i
    elif i.endswith('-'):
      tempstr+=i
    else:
      tempstr+=i
      outstr.append(tempstr)
      tempstr = ""
  return " ".join(outstr)


# There is a problem because of the ordering of 
# the if-else, it can only handle head or 
# trailing dashes, not both
a = join_morph(x)
print a 
a = join_morph(x).replace('-','')
print a

a = join_morph(join_morph(y)).replace('-','')
print a

a = join_morph(join_morph(z)).replace('-','')
print a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe:

```
import re
re.sub( ' *- *', '', txt )
```

**edit**: if you know that there will always be exactly *one* space before or after the dash, then go with the `replace` solution, otherwise if you expect to have strings like `high-rise`( no space before or after dash), or `high  -rise` (more than one space) or `high - rise` (one space on both sides), then the regular expression may fit better.

Answer (score 5):

```
x = "ko- zo- fond- w- a (* nga- bantawana )." #or any other input 
x = x.replace("- ", "").replace(" -", "")
```

It will remove all occurrences of "- " and " -" from the input effectively transforming strings as you need it.

Comment: @Ray and does not require import, but yes, performance is of greater value